Beamer toc active vs non active items
Consider the MWE below.
The main toc looks like this

and a partially covered toc looks like this

Note how the distance between the B-X items are larger than in the first image.
What am I missing here? Why is the style not used for the grayed out items. The effect is a lot easier to see if one makes the \vskip adjustment positive instead.
\documentclass[
aspectratio=169,
english,
]{beamer}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate{section in toc}{my ball unnumbered}
{\leavevmode\leftskip=2.25ex%
  \llap{%
    \raise0.1ex\beamer@usesphere{section number projected}{bigsphere}\kern1.25ex}%
  \inserttocsection\par\vskip-0.25\baselineskip}

\defbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{my ball unnumbered}
{\leavevmode\leftskip=5.1ex\llap{%
    \raise0.2ex\beamer@usesphere{subsection number projected}{smallsphere}\kern1ex}%
  \inserttocsubsection\par\vskip-0.25\baselineskip}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[my ball unnumbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[my ball unnumbered]

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{\textbf{Outline}}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\AtBeginSection[ ]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{\textbf{Outline}}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{\textbf{Outline}}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\section{A}
\subsection{A-1}
\subsection{A-2}

\section{B}
\subsection{B-1}
\subsection{B-2}
\subsection{B-3}
\subsection{B-4}
\subsection{B-5}

\end{document}


Shaded (sub)sections use an \unskip at the end:
\defbeamertemplate*{section in toc shaded}{default}[1][20]
{\begin{colormixin}{#1!parent.bg}\usebeamertemplate{section in toc}\end{colormixin}\unskip}

\defbeamertemplate*{subsection in toc shaded}{default}[1][20]
{\begin{colormixin}{#1!parent.bg}\usebeamertemplate{subsection in toc}\end{colormixin}\unskip}

You can avoid the problem by using \vspace{...} instead of \vskip:
\documentclass[
aspectratio=169,
english,
]{beamer}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate{section in toc}{my ball unnumbered}
{\leavevmode\leftskip=2.25ex%
  \llap{%
    \raise0.1ex\beamer@usesphere{section number projected}{bigsphere}\kern1.25ex}%
  \inserttocsection\par\vspace{-0.25\baselineskip}}

\defbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{my ball unnumbered}
{\leavevmode\leftskip=5.1ex\llap{%
    \raise0.2ex\beamer@usesphere{subsection number projected}{smallsphere}\kern1ex}%
  \inserttocsubsection\par\vspace{-0.25\baselineskip}}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[my ball unnumbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[my ball unnumbered]

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{\textbf{Outline}}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\AtBeginSection[ ]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{\textbf{Outline}}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{\textbf{Outline}}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\section{A}
\subsection{A-1}
\subsection{A-2}

\section{B}
\subsection{B-1}
\subsection{B-2}
\subsection{B-3}
\subsection{B-4}
\subsection{B-5}

\end{document}



Had missed the consequence of the \unskip. Thanks.

@daleif You're welcome!
